# Can humans go to hibernation?

Tags: human-biology

Like squirrel undergoes hibernation during unfavourable periods if we induced the hibernation causing pitutary hormones in the human blood stream, can humans go to hibernation?

Comment: This is unclear. You ask if we can go into hibernation, then say if we *induced* hibernation. Those are two different things. What exactly are you asking? If your question is, "Can metabolism slow down during times of decreased food," then please ask that. If your question is, "Can we manipulate hormones to cause metabolism slow down during times of decreased food," then please ask that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humans cannot hibernate. There are a number of reasons why we would not expect them to do so.

Hibernation is thought to be an evolutionary adaptation to cold temperatures, and food scarcity, (perhaps also predator avoidance). Humans evolved in tropical regions with an abundance of food, and are also considered apex predators. There was thus no evolutionary pressure.

If we were to induce `sleep` with the relevant pitutary hormones. Humans would likely die, if they do not have any life support.